# Creating a Date Range from Multiple Rows Based on a Single Date

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, date-range, gaps-and-islands

I have a user table with following fields: User_ID, Email, Used_date.

[image: Original Table]

As we can see, a user can switch to multiple emails over period. From **used_date** field I want to create date range fields (Email_Start_Date and Email_End_Date). They will store a time period when a user has used that email.

[image: Expected Table]

Its possible that a user can switch back to an older email. In this case same email will have two date ranges.

Also I want to fill the gap between last day of previous email and start date of current email.

For example if user used  someone@gmail.com for a period of 8/28/2020 - 8/31/2020.

Further he switched to someone1@gmail.com on 9/3/2020.

Then in output someone@gmail.com will have a date range of 8/28/2020 - 9/2/2020.

This is a case of gaps-and-islands. But I don't know how to implement this.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest just the difference of row numbers and aggregation:

```
select user_id, email, min(used_date) as email_start_date,
       lead(min(used_date)) over (partition by user_id order by min(used_date)) - interval '1 day' as email_end_date
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id order by used_date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id, email order by used_date) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by user_id, email, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

Actually, you can also do this with `lag()` and no aggregation:

```
select user_id, email, min(used_date) as email_start_date,
       lead(used_date) over (partition by user_id order by used_date) - interval '1 day' as email_end_date
from (select t.*,
             lag(email) over (partition by user_id order by used_date) as prev_email
      from t
     ) t
where prev_email is null or prev_email <> email;
```

This second one is simple.  It just keeps the rows where the email changes (or the row where the data starts for the user).  It then uses `lead()` to get the end date.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=724b1bc0d95994dc40bd225d92136759) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon. Your first suggestion worked perfectly. Second one using lag is failing for some of the email sequences. I'm trying to figure out but I don't see any pattern. Anyway I am good now. Once again thanks for your help!

Comment: @Thinkpad . . . Hmmm.  It might behave strangely if there are duplicate dates.

Answer (score 0):

Next time, paste your data as text, so we don't have to type it back ...

Do you mean this? I prefer an "infinite date" instead of a NULL value for the last until-date - and I prefer a "session id" to an "island identifier", they're usually called like that in clickstream and IoT analyses ...

```
WITH
indata(userid,email,used_dt) AS (
          SELECT 1,'someone@gmail.com' , DATE '2020-08-28'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'someone@gmail.com' , DATE '2020-08-29'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'someone@gmail.com' , DATE '2020-08-30'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'someone@gmail.com' , DATE '2020-08-31'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'someone1@gmail.com', DATE '2020-09-03'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'someone1@gmail.com', DATE '2020-09-05'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'someone1@gmail.com', DATE '2020-09-07'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'someone@gmail.com',  DATE '2020-09-09'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'bob@gmail.com'     , DATE '2019-07-12'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'alice@newmail.com' , DATE '2020-08-08'
)
,
with_change_counter AS (
SELECT 
  userid
, email
, used_dt AS used_from_dt
, CASE 
    WHEN LAG(email,1,'') OVER(
      PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY used_dt
    ) <> email 
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0 
  END AS counter
, LEAD(used_dt,1,'9999-12-31') OVER(
    PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY used_dt
  ) AS used_until_dt
  FROM indata
)
,with_sess_id AS (
  SELECT
    userid
  , email
  , used_from_dt
  , used_until_dt
  , SUM(counter) OVER(PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY used_from_dt) AS sessid
  , counter
  FROM with_change_counter
) 
SELECT
  userid
, MAX(email) AS email
, MIN(used_from_dt) AS email_start_date
, MAX(used_until_dt) AS email_end_date
FROM with_sess_id
GROUP BY
  sessid
, userid
ORDER BY
  userid
, sessid
, email
;
-- out  userid |       email        | email_start_date | email_end_date 
-- out --------+--------------------+------------------+----------------
-- out       1 | someone@gmail.com  | 2020-08-28       | 2020-09-03
-- out       1 | someone1@gmail.com | 2020-09-03       | 2020-09-09
-- out       1 | someone@gmail.com  | 2020-09-09       | 9999-12-31
-- out       2 | bob@gmail.com      | 2019-07-12       | 9999-12-31
-- out       3 | alice@newmail.com  | 2020-08-08       | 9999-12-31
```

Comment: Thanks Marcothesane for your suggestion. I tried to past my data from excel. But it was converted to image. Next time I use insert table statement.